# Extract lines with "number string number number" and write it to data frame

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, extract

My data set looks as follows (excerpt):

```
2.000 Company A 8.876 0,02
248 Enterprise B 26.028 0,07
193
dasdasdasd (asasas) sdasdasd
adsadsd asdasd asasa asassaas asas 
asas asas 31. January 2018 (continue)
asdasd – 99,00% (31. March 2017 – 99,98%) (continue)
amasdasd asas
asasas asas
asas asssssssssss
DDD
asdasdads in %
asdasd adasd asddasad 
(continue)
415 Company C Ltd. 21.412 0,06
668 Enterprise D AG 17.332 0,05
1.240 Company E GmbH 31.394 0,09
798 Enterprise OHG 52.586 0,14
```

I only want to extract those lines where I have a "number string number number" so that my data should in the end look as follows:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Colum 4
2.000 Company A 8.876 0,02
248 Enterprise B 26.028 0,07
415 Company C Ltd. 21.412 0,06
668 Enterprise D AG 17.332 0,05
1.240 Company E GmbH 31.394 0,09
798 Enterprise OHG 52.586 0,14
```

Any idea how to do it? Basically, where I need help in particular is to create the regular expression in order to filter for those lines and to write the extracted information to a data frame so that I can perform some analysis on that.

Comment: What is the type of your dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
data = """2.000 Company A 8.876 0,02
248 Enterprise B 26.028 0,07
193
dasdasdasd (asasas) sdasdasd
adsadsd asdasd asasa asassaas asas 
asas asas 31. January 2018 (continue)
asdasd – 99,00% (31. March 2017 – 99,98%) (continue)
amasdasd asas
asasas asas
asas asssssssssss
DDD
asdasdads in %
asdasd adasd asddasad 
(continue)
415 Company C Ltd. 21.412 0,06
668 Enterprise D AG 17.332 0,05
1.240 Company E GmbH 31.394 0,09
798 Enterprise OHG 52.586 0,14"""

reader = StringIO(data)
pattern = re.compile(r'([\d\.\,]+)\s+(\D*)([\d\.\,]+)\s([\d\.\,]+)$')
rows = []
for row in reader:
    match = pattern.search(row)
    if match:
        rows.append([match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3), match.group(4)])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4"])
```

---

**Output**

```py
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
0   2.000   Company A   8.876   0,02
1   248 Enterprise B    26.028  0,07
2   415 Company C Ltd.  21.412  0,06
3   668 Enterprise D AG 17.332  0,05
4   1.240   Company E GmbH  31.394  0,09
5   798 Enterprise OHG  52.586  0,14
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the regex for your required query:

```
\d*[.]?\d* [a-zA-Z]+ \d*[.]?\d* \d*[.]?\d*
```

How to parse your data and import it to your dataframe is a task I will leave up to you.

Use this to match "number (int or decimal) string number number" with every line of your data.

Answer (score 0):

this will meet your requirement,

```
pattern = r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]*\.? [a-zA-Z]*\.?[a-zA-Z]*\.?.+ [-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+ [-+]?[0-9]*\,?[0-9]'
out=re.findall(pattern,yourstring)
```